# Easiest process for me to apply textures, created externally, to my models

Tags: texturing, uv, workflow

For the first time I'm working with an artist who is going to be creating the textures for the models I create in Blender.  Up till now I had been building the models and the texturing them myself using pre-built textures from websites.

My question is:
What is the easiest process for me to apply the textures our artist creates to my model?  Should I give the artist the UV Map from my model, or should I just get textures from the artist and fit them to the UV Map?  Basically I have no idea how this process works in a professional environment.

Comment: What did your artist say about what workflow she would prefer?

Comment: She is new to this as well.and doesn't have any knowledge of 3d modeling.

Comment: I have no experience with this, but it makes sense to me if you would send her your model, let her make the uv map and textures, and send you the textured model back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to UV unwrap your model, lay it out the way it should be (and then don't change it). Send that UV layout to the texture artist.

That is the only way you can have textures custom built for any 3D object.
The person painting the texture, you or somebody else makes no difference, has to know where to put and how to shape the texture. (How could you paint a room if you did not know what the room looked like?)

---

You can export the UVs from the *UV/Image Editor*'s header by clicking on *UVs* > *Export UV Layout*.
Blender's file browser will open up letting you choose the name and location for the new image. There are some important settings on the left side.
[image: Export UV Layout options]

1. Make sure the export size is the same size that your target UV map will be.
2. Set the *Fill Opacity* to something higher then the default of .25 (the default is too transparent to be useful). I like 1 as it is completely opaque which gives a good base layer to work off of.